# How to click on button using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```html
<a class="button_small button_orange btn_apply" onclick="javascript:showApplyJob();">Apply Now</a>
```

How to click on button using selenium in python?

url of the website : [Link](https://www.olyvr.com/candidates/myjobs/viewjobdetail.jsp?id=10757435&teamid=465&score=72&log=2)

tried code :-

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.jobWrap > div.jobDetailWrap > div.job.hasScorecard > div.applyBtn_m > a').click()
```

Comment: Share us the code that you have tried to achieve the same?

Comment: This is syntax of code i have tried but its not working! driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.jobWrap > div.jobDetailWrap > div.job.hasScorecard > div.applyBtn_m > a').click()

Comment: what error you are getting ? Seems your css selector is worong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.button_small.button_orange.btn_apply")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='applyBtn']>a")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class='applyBtn']>a').click()
```